# java queue to queue calculaton not satisfied

Tags: java, linked-list, priority-queue

I'm having a slight issue trying to see where I'm going wrong with the following piece of code:

```
public void processNextJob() {
        /*
         * 1. get # of free CPU's still avaialble
         * 2. get top most job from priority queue
         * 3. run job - put to CPU queue
         * 4. develop a CPU queue here
         * 5. count cores against freeCPUS and some sort of calculation to sort run times
         */
        int freeCPUS = 500;
        int availableCPUS = 0;
        JobRequest temp = new JobRequest(); // initalised to new JobRequest
        Queue q = new LinkedList();

        while (true) {
            int size = q.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                temp = (JobRequest) q.peek();
                if (temp != null) {
                    availableCPUS += temp.getCores();
                }
            }
            if ((freeCPUS - availableCPUS) >= 0) {
                JobRequest nextJob = schedulerPriorityQueue.closestDeadlineJob(freeCPUS - availableCPUS); // returns top job from queue
                if (nextJob != null) {
                    System.out.println("Top priority / edf job:");
                    printJob(nextJob);
                    q.add(nextJob);

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Job = null");
                }

            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (temp != null) {

            System.out.println("Execution Queue");

            for(Object jr : q){
             printJob((JobRequest)jr);//print all elements in q   
            }

        }

    }
```

What's happening here is that I'm adding the top element from a priorityqueue and adding it to a new LinkedList. But the jobs I'm taking off the priorityqueue have a item with a value called "cores". I'm trying to get it to take as many jobs off as possible while staying under the core limit.

`temp.getCores()` is where I get the cores value

The issue I'm having is that it's not adding them correctly to my linkedlist queue, the value it takes in doesnt change. My queue displays 5 outputs with a core value of "160" but I've set a 500 cap, so the queue doesnt satisfy it at all

I dont see where I'm going wrong in the adding the values from the priorityqueue to make my available CPUS reach the designated limit of it being under 500.

EDIT:

```
public JobRequest closestDeadlineJob(int freeCPUS) {
        // find top job to determine if other jobs for date need to be considered
        JobRequest nextJob = scheduledJobs.peek(); // return top most job

        if (nextJob != null) {

            System.out.println("Found top EDF job:");
            printJob( nextJob );

            // what is it's date?
            Date highestRankedDate = nextJob.getConvertedDeadlineDate();

            // create a temporary queue to work out priorities of jobs with same deadline
            JobPriorityQueue schedulerPriorityQueue = new JobPriorityQueue();

            // add the top job to priority queue
            //schedulerPriorityQueue.addJob(nextJob);

            for (JobRequest jr : scheduledJobs) {

                // go through scheduled jobs looking for all jobs with same date
                if (jr.getConvertedDeadlineDate().equals(highestRankedDate)) {
                    // same date deadline, soadd to scheduler priority queue
                    schedulerPriorityQueue.addJob(jr);
                    System.out.println("Adding following job to priority queue:");
                    printJob(jr);
                }
            }

            JobRequest highestPriorityJob = schedulerPriorityQueue.poll();
            // this is the item at the top of the PRIORTY JOB queue to return 

            // remove that item from scheduledJobs
            scheduledJobs.remove(highestPriorityJob);


            return highestPriorityJob;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this statement ever execute - `System.out.println("Top priority / edf job:");`?

Comment: yes it runs tells my my top job from my priorityqueue then adds that job to the linked list, it's just a check for me to see it's working, it all runs through but its the issue with how I'm adding the cores which is not working

Comment: And may we know what the `closestDeadlineJob` method is doing?

Comment: It appears that `closestDeadlineJob` is not returning the expected `JobRequest`.

Comment: When it runs through, it returns me the top of my queue, looking at it on debug it seems to be returning it fine, just the calculating of the cores in the new one is well off, editted to add closestDeadlineJob

Comment: I see that the argument `freeCPUS` is not used in `closestDeadlineJob`. Is it intended?

Comment: It is intended, as my processNextJob function will not run if I remove it:
used in conjunction with - JobRequest nextJob = schedulerPriorityQueue.closestDeadlineJob(freeCPUS - availableCPUS);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to have a look here.

In your `for()` loop where you increment the `availableCPUS` variable, you are always taking the `head` of the `Queue`:

`temp = (JobRequest) q.peek();`

And because `peek()` does not remove an element from the queue, you end up assigning the same `JobRequest` to `temp`.

Try using an `Iterator` instead of the `for`:

```
availableCPUS = 0;
Iterator<JobRequest> it = q.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    temp = it.next();
    if (temp != null) {
        availableCPUS += temp.getCores();
    }
}
```

Also, I think you need to set `availableCPUS` to `0` for every iteration of the while loop to be able to count the cores correctly.

So you should be placing `availableCPUS = 0;` just above the Iterator initialization.

Comment: ok but if I change that to:
temp = (JobRequest) q.poll();
which will remove the top, my q is empty and I can't print any of my execution stack out

Comment: You need not use `poll` if you're using an iterator.

Comment: ah excellent, by implementing what you put before and making sure available CPU is within my while(true) it satisfies the limit set, thankyou very much